# Prove that $\Pr(g(X)\geq c) \leq \frac{E(g(X))}{c}$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, inequality, random-variables

Let $X$ be a random variable and $g:R\to R\; \ni \;g(x)\geq 0 \; \forall x\in R$ and let $c > 0$. Then, show that, (provided the expectation exists)
$$\Pr(g(X)\geq c) \leq \frac{E(g(X))}{c}$$

I will prove when $X$ is continuous. Let $f$ be the PDF of $X$, then

$E(g(X)) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty g(x)f(x) \, dx = \int_{g(x) \geq c}g(x)f(x) \, dx + \int_{g(x)<c}g(x)f(x) \, dx \geq \int_{g(x)\geq c} g(x)f(x) \, dx \geq c\cdot \int_{g(x)\geq c} f(x) \, dx = c\cdot \Pr(g(X)\geq c)$

Which proves it. Is this correct proof?

Comment: $X$ may not have a pdf, so a general proof is preferable. This looks just like Markov's inequality.

Comment: @StubbornAtom its a general case of Markov's, do you know this inequality's name

Comment: As noted by StubbornAtom, take a look at Markov inequality. The logic of the general proof is similar to your proof, just substitute integrals with expectations and rely on indicator functions.

Comment: What is the need to write $g(X)$ instead of $Y$? It is the ordinary Markov's inequality with $Y\geq 0$ and $c>0$: $Pr(Y\geq c)\leq \frac{E(Y)}{c}$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $1\{ g(X) \geq c \}$ be the indicator function of the event $\{ g(X) \geq c \}$. Now you can see directly that $c \cdot 1\{ g(X) \geq c \}\leq g(X)$. If you take the expectation of this inequality you get
\begin{align*}
&&\mathbb E[c\cdot 1\{ g(X) \geq c \}] &\leq \mathbb E[g(X)]\\
\Leftrightarrow &&\mathbb P(g(X)\geq c) &\leq \frac{\mathbb E[g(X)]}{c}
\end{align*}

Since $\mathbb E[1\{A\}]=\mathbb P(A)$.

Comment: Is there flaw in my proof? I am getting confused with indicator function

Comment: You cannot write $E(g(X))=\int_{-\infty}^\infty g(x) f(x) dx$ in general, $X$ could be something unrelated like a fruit or anything. Otherwise your proof is more or less the same as mine.

Comment: I am assuming $X$ to be Continuous random variable.